# Find the index of a list of tuples with nondistinct values in first index of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to get the index of a list of 2-tuples in Python, where the 0 index of each tuple is `'a'`:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

So I use the following list comprehension to try to find out which index is returned, correct?

```
index_list = [x for x, y in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if x[0] == 'a']
```

Which gives the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5d47328b7d9a> in <module>()
----> 1 index_list = [x for x, y in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if x[0] ==     'a']

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I find out the index associated with searching the list of tuples for the value in the 0th index being equal to `'a'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value `y` to compare not the index `x`:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
index_list = [x for x, y in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if y[0] == 'a']
```

Now `index_list` is `[0, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is the index. You should be accessing the first element of `y -> y[0]`.  `y` is each tuple in your list. You can also unpack:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
index_list = [ind for ind,  (a, _) in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if a == 'a']
print(index_list)
[0, 1, 2]
```

If you `print(list(enumerate(list_of_tuples)))` you can see the first element is the index and the second your tuple:

```
[(0, ('a', 1)), (1, ('a', 2)), (2, ('a', 3))]
```

So you are trying to index `0 -> 0[0]` with `x[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend you verify your data.

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
print list(enumerate(list_of_tuples))
# [(0, ('a', 1)), (1, ('a', 2)), (2, ('a', 3))]
    ^   ^-----^
    x     y
```

When you understand how to unpack to use the data, it's easy to do it.

```
index_list = [x for x, y in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if y[0] == 'a']
print index_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x,y in enumerate(my_tuples):
    print x,"=x"
    print y,"=y"
```

you should immediatly see the problem with `x[0] == 'a'`

I believe

```
index_list = [x for x, y in enumerate(list_of_tuples) if y[0] == 'a']
```

should work better for you